# Want to use woocommerce payment gateways out of woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment

I have a question regarding to the woocommerce payment gateways. I have a scenario in which I have to create the packages which are being saved into the options table, these are not related to any post types but are purchasable by users.

What I need is the payment gateways the woocommerce is using, I needed to know if there is any hook, any class that I can extend or any other way that I can use the woocommerce payment gateway to buy my packages.

What I wanted is that I simply pass through few parameters like (Amount, quantity, Package Name and return URL) to a function and it should return me the transaction ID on return page. I don't want to use the products and orders for this because I am already using them on my site also the current functionality is working fine I just need to change the gateways so it uses the woocommerce.

Comment: Yes it is possible, what payment gateway are you using.?

Comment: I want to use all the gateways the woo-commerce is using

Comment: When the action has to be triggered ( the payment action ), whenever user tries to place an order.? those packages you mentioned those are submitted by users.? is there any action triggered at the time those package submitted.?